# How to Access particular page of a HTTPS secured website via HTTP request.?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

I want to allow http request to a particular page. But currently all requests are redirecting to HTTPS

Here is Htaccess redirect Code

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you share the part of the configuration with http->https redirect?

Comment: Are you aware that `#` is the syntax for comments in Apache configuration files?

Comment: yea i am aware of that @ÁlvaroGonzález . my bad, i was checking something that time i commented it.